# Problema con Laravel y autoload

Tags: php, laravel, composer

Tengo que actualizar un sitio web que desarrollé con Laravel y se me presenta el siguiente mensaje de error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class
>   'ComposerAutoloaderInitbb529bac053ceed05e1be22099cc76f1' not found in
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/heycom/Abbey/vendor/autoload.php:7 Stack
>   trace:
>
> 0 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/heycom/Abbey/artisan(18): require()
>
> 1 {main}   thrown in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/heycom/Abbey/vendor/autoload.php on line 7

Me fijé en mis archivos y la carpeta composer no la tenía y el archivo autoload.php está suelto dentro de la carpeta Vendor.

Que tenga instalado el programa de GitHub, ¿puede estar complicando algo?

---

yo había desarrollado el sitio y lo subi. 
Ahora hace unas semanas, empece a usar GitHub y lo subí, para tenerlo a mi disposición por si tenía alguna urgencia.
Esta semana, necesito hacer unos ajustes y cuándo quiero correr el sitio de forma local, me tira ese error.

Comment: explica un poco mas que es lo que has hecho para que deje de funcionar, o es que has clonado el repositorio en tu pc local y estas teniendo estos problemas para hacer que la pagina te funcione en tu pc?

Comment: me parece que te puede faltar correr el comando para instalar las dependecias de laravel: composer update

Answer (score 2):

No sé cómo ni qué habrás subido a GitHub, pero sin duda tienes un error con las dependencias de Composer.

Lo más sencillo sería que borres en tu proyecto local la carpeta `vendor` y que ejecutes en tu línea de comando: `composer install`.

Por último, puedes limpiar el caché de la aplicación:

```
php artisan config:clear

php artisan cache:clear
```

Comment: gracias por tu ayuda